# How to linearize the sum of a product of two decision variables in LP?

Tags: python, linear-programming

Being new to Linear Programming and Gurobi, I am dealing with an Integer Linear program where I have two **binary** **decision** **variables** defined as **B[u_v, x_y]** and **A[u_x]**, I am trying to implement this constraint in **Gurobi** via **Python** but I am stuck on how to translate the **sum of the product of the two decision variables** defined in this loop :

```
for each edge(u,v) in Set_of_edges:
    for each vertex x in Set_of_vertices:
        Sum_over(y) (B[u_v,x_y]) * A[u_x] == 1
```

From this [book](http://www.win.tue.nl/~wscor/OW/2MMD40/AIMMS_modeling.pdf), it has to be linearized but I am not able to do it.
Anyone could shed some light and provide me with some insights ?

Thanks

Comment: The product of two decision variables is not a linear program.

Comment: Linearization-potential depends on the types of those decision-variables.

Comment: @sascha Exactly - if B or A is a binary decision variable, there are some ways to handle it via MIP. Otherwise, this is a nonlinear program.

Comment: @GregGlockner I agree with you. I forgot to mention that they are binary variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you got two binary-variables `x` and `y`, you can add a new auxiliary binary variable `z = x*y` by these constraints:

- `z <= x`
- `z <= y`
- `z >= x + y - 1`

As i can't follow your task (incomplete pseudo-code) you will have to do the rest yourself, using the newly introduced variable `z`.

Comment: Thanks. In this case, I will have also to do the summation on z right ?

Comment: Depends on the task, but ```z``` is a variable equal to the product ```x*y```. If you want to sum over those products, yes.

Comment: I mean the task invovles the sum over the product of the two binary decision variables.