# How can I dis-aggregate combination statistics using a solver?

Tags: optimization, solver, nonlinear-optimization, mixed-integer-programming, glpk

I'm trying to reverse an aggregation in a form so that when the aggregation is performed again on the dis-aggregated data it will result in the exact same aggregated data set.

The data is about users and their usage of software applications.

What I have is a triangular matrix describing the combinations of software used (i.e. 2 Users use software 1 and software 3)

```
   S1 S2 S3 S4 S5  
S1     1  2  0  1  
S2        2  1  2  
S3           0  2  
S4              1
```

What I also have is the number of users = 5.

What I would like to get is something like this (e.g. meaning User2 is using S1, S2, S3):

```
      S1 S2 S3 S4 S5
User1  1  0  0  0  0  
User2  1  1  1  0  0 
User3  0  1  0  1  1
User4  0  1  1  0  1
User5  1  0  1  0  1
```

I tried GLPK but I don't see a way of getting the constrains right. My idea was to check if the sumproduct of the columns (e.g. S1 & S2 ) is constrained by the values in the triangular matrix (in the first case = 1) but the product appears to make it a non-linear problem.

Is using a solver the right approach for this problem?
Is there a way to solve this in GLPK, and if not which solver should I use?

Answer (score 0):

The product of two binary variables can be linearized, to make it a MILP, like in the example at [How to linearize the sum of a product of two decision variables in LP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898257/how-to-linearize-the-sum-of-a-product-of-two-decision-variables-in-lp)
Once linearized, the model should be solvable using any MILP solver (provided it isn't too large).

However, there are likely to be multiple solutions. Whether that is a problem depends on the context. For example, an alternative solution to your example is:

```
      S1 S2 S3 S4 S5
User1  0  1  0  1  1  
User2  1  0  1  0  1 
User3  1  1  1  0  0
User4  0  0  0  0  0
User5  0  1  1  0  1
```

Comment: Thank you. How did you come up with the alternative solution? I am looking at a rather large dataset where i will have over 100k Users and over 1000 Software applications.

Comment: I used Excel Solver to create the alt solution.
I doubt that 100k x 1000 is solvable as a MILP. Even if it is, there will likely be an enormous number of alt solutions, so would it be useful to find one of them? e.g. unless there are additional constraints, all row orders are alt solutions, so a solution doesn't tell us which user has what software.